# Website Mobile friendliness bulk check - GA integration?

Tags: web, mobile, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, mobile-website

I am looking for a way to report to Google Analytics a metric that would be mobile-friendliness check (yes / no).

Is there any way to automatically download this result to GA using some integration?

At present, each page is scanned manually using google mobile-friendly test tool and later I save the result as yes / no to excel.

I am looking for an automatic solution. Something that could use GTM, GA, JS scripting solutions. I am of course open to any other suggestions that would solve my problem.

Please help

Comment: StackOverflow is not a software recommendation site. Questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

"yes/no" is a dimension, not a metric (metrics are numeric and add up).

If you are testing your urls with an external tool in any case, you can do a data upload. Create a csv that has the url as first column, and the yes/no value as second column.

Create a hit based custom dimension in GA with a name of e.g. "mobile friendly".

In your property settings, go to "Data Import". Click "create", select "custom data" as Data Set type, and select the views you want the data imported into.

In "Data Set schema" select "page" as key ("page" in this case means url) and the custom dimension as key in to "Data import" field.

Save your settings.

Now that you have created a data source, you can click on "manage uploads" and upload the csv file. The data import will not match the first row in your csv to the "page" dimension in GA, and will fill in the values for the "mobile friendly" dimension.

Alas in the free version of GA the import will only apply to incoming hits, it will not apply to data that is already collected. So you should run your external tests regularly and update your data import with a new upload if anything changes (data processing will take at least 24 hours, so you cannot update all too often).